# OS for controlling CNC machine?

Tags: operating-systems

RISC OS, PiDora, Raspbian, Arch, etc. are all available for the Pi.  [All are distributed](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads) by the Raspberry Pi Foundation, but which will work the best as a control system for a 3D printer or a CNC machine with 5 Axis?

These are both processor intensive projects and need a robust OS to be successful.  Any insight would appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any OS could work for this, as long has you hook up the Raspberry Pi to the CNC machine properly and have the proper software on the OS to interface with the machine.

---

That said, I found [this forum post](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=33809) detailing success with [LinuxCNC](http://www.linuxcnc.org/) on the Raspberry Pi.  Here is some information about the LinuxCNC:

> **About the software**
>
> - LinuxCNC (the Enhanced Machine Control) is a software system for    computer control of machine tools such as milling machines and
>     lathes.
> - LinuxCNC is free software with open source code. Current versions of    LinuxCNC are entirely licensed under the GNU General Public
>     License    and Lesser GNU General Public License (GPL and LGPL)
> - LinuxCNC provides:
>
>   - several graphical user interfaces including one for touch screens
>   - an interpreter for "G-code" (the RS-274 machine tool programming         language)
>   - a realtime motion planning system with look-ahead operation of    low-level machine electronics such as sensors and motor drives
>   - an easy to use "breadboard" layer for quickly creating a unique    configuration for your machine
>   - a software PLC programmable with ladder diagrams
>   - easy installation with .deb packages or a Live-CD
>
>   It does not provide drawing (CAD - Computer Aided Design) or G-code generation from the drawing (CAM - Computer Automated
>     Manufacturing) functions.
> - It can simultaneously move up to 9 axes and supports a variety of    interfaces.
> - The control can operate true servos (analog or PWM) with the feedback    loop closed by the LinuxCNC software at the computer, or
>     open loop    with "step-servos" or stepper motors.
> - Motion control features include: cutter radius and length    compensation, path deviation limited to a specified tolerance, lathe
>     threading, synchronized axis motion, adaptive feedrate, operator feed 
>     override, and constant velocity control.
> - Support for non-Cartesian motion systems is provided via custom    kinematics modules. Available architectures include hexapods (Stewart 
>     platforms and similar concepts) and systems with rotary joints to
>     provide motion such as PUMA or SCARA robots.
> - LinuxCNC runs on Linux using real time extensions. Support currently    exists for version 2.4 and 2.6 Linux kernels with real
>     time    extensions applied by RT-Linux or RTAI patches.

[Here is a customized Raspbian image for LinuxCNC](http://wiki.linuxcnc.org/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?RaspbianXenomaiBuild).

[Here is a demo of it on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WLIo7TA82xE&feature=youtu.be).